# How to implement ring settings for Enigma machine in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I implemented my vision of the Enigma machine in PHP. And it works great until I set the ring settings. I understand that this should somehow shift the position, but I'm stuck with this.

You can check project [here](https://github.com/yaroslavche/enigma).

Main idea - `map` method in `AbstractRotor`:

```php
public function map(int $position, bool $reverse = false): int
{
    $map = $reverse ? array_flip($this->map) : $this->map;
    $itemsCount = count($map);
    $mapPosition = ($position + $this->currentPosition) % $itemsCount;
    $offset = $mapPosition - $position;
    $index = $map[$mapPosition] - $offset;
    if ($offset !== 0) {
        $index = $itemsCount + $index;
        $index %= $itemsCount;
    }
    return $index;
}
```

If `reverse` - just swap key and values in mapping array.
For getting index in map array, need calculate `$position + $this->currentPosition` and fit to bounds.
`$offset` exists when rotor is rotated.
As I can understand, here must be somehow used `ringPosition`.

I created test data for this case (tests/EnigmaTest.php#L94), and it does not work =) I would really appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.

**UPD.**
I am grateful for this desire for clarification! =) Also may be I can somehow figure out how to do this when I try to describe the problem. As said: a good question is half the answer.

So, in a nutshell: the Enigma machine is working. But without the ability to change the position of the ring ([Rotor Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_rotor_details#Rotor_offset)). And I really tried somehow to use `$this->ringPosition` in the`AbstractRotor::map` method. But I don't understand, so I need help.

How it's working?
By default AbstractRotor has a ringPosition eq 0. This means that wire connects from 0 index (IDK, if I can describe this in right way, hope you understand what I mean). For example, rotor `I` A -> E, B -> K, C -> M, and so on. But if set ring setting (ringstellung, offset), for example, for B, then A -> K, B -> M, and so on. This is how I understand that, but I can be wrong.

If you shall clone repo and uncomment https://github.com/yaroslavche/enigma/blob/master/tests/EnigmaTest.php#L94, then this test willn't pass. You can check cipher at many [simulators](https://meinenigma.com/enigma-simulators/) (I suggest to use `Summerside Makerspace`, the first one link, but others also useful in some cases).

So, main problem - when I try to change `AbstarctRotor::$ringPosition`, then it wouldn't work. You can set that property, but machine works only when ringPosition equals 0. How to make correct offset including `ringPosition`? And now it's just unused property that not affects `map` (ring offset always 0). I tried, for example, `- $this->ringPosition`, but I don't understand what I must to do with that `ringPosition` in `map` method.